# Como atualizar resultados do MySQL automaticamente com JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Galera como faço para atualizar consultas do MySQL automaticamente com JavaScript?

Estava dando uma olhada no site e achei algo que me ajudou só que coloquei em meu site e quando fui ver os processos do servidor o segundo arquivo consulta.php estava abrindo mais de 150 processos (*deixando o servidor super lento*) existe alguma forma mais pratica para resolver meu problema?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doRefresh(){
    $("#contagem").load("consulta.php");
}
$(function() {
    setInterval(doRefresh, 100);
});
</script>
```

Arquivo consulta.php

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";

$data = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teste WHERE ativo='1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;")); 
$t = time() - $data['tempo'];   
echo "<font color='green'><h1>Tempo: $t</h1></font>";
mysql_close($mysql); ?>
```

Comment: Que tal aumentar o tempo para 500 milissegundos ou mais? Realmente é necessário que essa consulta seja feita 10 vezes em 1 segundo?

Comment: Seguinte, o "setInteval" faz com que todo o código dentro dele seja repetido e aquele '100' é o tempo de delay em que esse código se repete. Como ele é assincrono, vai gerar chamada encima de chamada fazendo com que o servidor fique lento.
Minha sugestão é que vc aumente esse tempo do setInterval. procure ver quanto tempo demora o select para ser feito e coloque essa média de tempo, um pouco acima se possível

Comment: A forma mais prática de trabalhar com dados em tempo real é criar um serviço de websocket. Pra isso existem milhões de implementações como o nodejs. Pesquise sobre o assunto aqui mesmo no SO, existem várias perguntas sobre isso. Só não recomendo trabalhar com socket em PHP, pois podem trazer alguns problemas de memória.

Answer (score 1):

Legal se possivel era alterar para `setInterval(doRefresh, 1000);` 
E verifique se seu servidor tem fechamento de conexão automático se não tens que fazer via código.